# Как поднять кнопки над клавиатурой?

Tags: android, xml

Есть XML. Вопрос в следующем: когда я хочу ввести текст в последний edittext появляется клавиатура которая перекрывает кнопки. Хотелось бы что-бы они поднимались наверх и не закрывались клавиатурой

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` - не помог
 `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` - не помог

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    tools:context=".CardMarkerActivity">


    <!---BLOCK 1-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/CategoryStyle"
            android:text="@string/latlng" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_latitude"
                style="@style/EditorFieldStyle"
                android:hint="@string/latitude"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:autofillHints="" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_longitude"
                style="@style/EditorFieldStyle"
                android:hint="@string/longitude"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:autofillHints="" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



    <!---BLOCK 2-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/CategoryStyle"
            android:text="@string/titlemarker" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_title_marker"
                style="@style/EditorFieldStyle"
                android:hint="@string/titlemarker2"
                android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZАаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:autofillHints="" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



    <!---BLOCK 3-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/CategoryStyle"
            android:text="@string/date" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                style="@style/CategoryStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:hint="@string/selectdate" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <!---BLOCK 4-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_dept"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/CategoryStyle"
            android:text="@string/Depth" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_dept"
                style="@style/EditorFieldStyle"
                android:hint="@string/depth"
                android:digits="0123456789."
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:autofillHints="" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <!---BLOCK 5-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_number_of_fish"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/CategoryStyle"
            android:text="@string/Number" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_number_of_fish"
                style="@style/EditorFieldStyle"
                android:hint="@string/number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:autofillHints="" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <!---BLOCK 6-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/CategoryStyle"
            android:text="@string/Note"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_note"
                style="@style/EditorFieldStyle"
                android:hint="@string/note"
                android:autofillHints=""/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <!---BLOCK 7-->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:text="@string/cancel"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:text="@string/ok"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: можно попробовать android:elevation = "5dp например".

Comment: elevation - высота view. Не решило данную проблему. Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

В манифесте к активити `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
В активити xml `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` у рутового контейнера, где схема указывается.

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло. Видимо проблема в самой разметке

Comment: Более дельно не смогу посоветовать, только угадывать.

Answer (score 0):

В общем обернул все в `ScrollView` - тоже не плохо в принципе)

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте к activity пишем:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```